# Java - Unit testing a void method using Matchers

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, matcher

I am trying to test a void method such as following:

```
@Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent myEvent) {
        if (myEvent instanceof ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
            ConfigurableEnvironment myEnv= ((ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) myEvent).getEnvironment();
            setSystemVariables(myEnv);
        }

    }
```

I am using Matchers and here is the unit test (which obviously is not testing anything)

```
@Test
    public void testOnApplicationEvent() {
        loggingListener.onApplicationEvent(any(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent.class));
    }
```

Two issues:
1. The error I get from the build is "Invalid use of Matchers" and test doesn't pass in my Jenkins build (but passes in idea IDE)
2. How to test these methods to keep the test coverage percentage up to a desired level

Answer (score 1):

1 - This issue because `any` is used incorrectly. Refer the `Mockito` guide for details. Below my example does not use `any` and the problem will be gone.

2 - To cover 2 branches of `if` I would recommend below test cases.

```
@Test
public void onApplicationEventShouldSetEnvironmentWhenApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent() {
    ConfigurableEnvironment actualEnvironment = null;

    // Given a listener with overridden setSystemVariables() to store passed env.
    LoggingListener loggingListener = new LoggingListener() {
        @Override
        void setSystemVariables(ConfigurableEnvironment var){
            actualEnvironment = var;
        }
    };

    // Given some dummy environment which is delivered by an event.
    ConfigurableEnvironment expectedEnvironment = new ConfigurableEnvironment();

    // Given a mocked event with above dummy environment.
    ApplicationEvent mockedEvent = Mockito(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent.class);
    Mockito.when(mockedEvent.getEnvironment()).returns(expectedEnvironment);

    // When call a method under test
    loggingListener.onApplicationEvent(mockedEvent);

    // Then make sure the given environment was passed and set correctly
    assertSame(expectedEnvironment, actualEnvironment);
}

@Test
public void onApplicationEventShouldSkipNotApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent() {
    // Given a listener with overridden setSystemVariables() to fail the test if called.
    LoggingListener loggingListener = new LoggingListener() {
        @Override
        void setSystemVariables(ConfigurableEnvironment var){
            fail("This method should not be called");
        }
    };

    // Given a mocked other (not ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) event.
    ApplicationEvent mockedEvent = Mockito(UnknownEvent.class);

    // When call a method under test
    loggingListener.onApplicationEvent(mockedEvent);

    // Then make sure an environment was not asked at all.
    Mockito.verify(mockedEvent.getEnvironment(), never);
}
```

Note, this is not compilable code, because I don't know your full production code, so treat this as an idea to apply it on your real code with corresponding modifications.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will try and get back